# Widget setOnClickPendingIntent

Tags: android

So, I am having a hard time figuring out how to make my app widget work the way I want it to, or if its even possible.

The Widget has a `ImageView` and I assign a `setOnClickPendingIntent` to it. However, what I want to accomplish is basically just to instantiate a class and call a method in that class when the user taps the `ImageView` in the app widget. However, how can I make the `PendingIntent` do something else than just firing up an activity instead? Not sure if this made any sense, but I really appreciate the help.

```
           // Create an Intent to launch MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                    /**
                    /* However, I want to simply do something like this
                    /* MyClass mc = new MyClass(context);
                    /* mc.toggleEnable();
                    */

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageViewWidgetToggle, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` which will be received in your `AppWidgetProvider` class :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction("use_custom_class");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageViewWidgetToggle, pendingIntent);
```

and then in the `AppWidgetProvider` :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    String action = intent.getAction();
    String actionName = "use_custom_class";

    if (actionName.equals(action)) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(context);
        mc.toggleEnable();
    }
}
```

Have a look at [the docs about PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for details on the flags to use. I hope I understood your question correctly and that my answer made sense to you :) If not, don't hesitate to let me know...

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need! Ill give it a go and see how it fares and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Btw, you have a parenthesis too much on line 3 ;)

Comment: Glad I could help ! Good catch for the typo, one can never be too careful with copy/pasting ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to change the widget background on button click, I used @2Dee 's answer. It didn't work for me until I updated the Widget after these changes:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget2x2);
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_layout2x2, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.border_radius);
//Don't forget to update the widget
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName me = new ComponentName(context, Widget2x2.class);
mgr.updateAppWidget(me, remoteViews);
```